# Declaring object onto the stack in class definition vs in constructor

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, variable-declaration

When I declare the "Level" object in the "LevelEditor" class definition like so, everything works fine:

```cpp
class LevelEditor
{
public:
    LevelEditor(int w, int h, Shader* shader)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                tile[x][y] = new WorldSprite(tileWidth * x, tileHeight * y, tileWidth, tileHeight, shader);
            }
        }
    }

    //...
private:

    //...
    Level level = Level(50, 50);

    WorldSprite* tile[300][300];

    //tile characteristics
    int tileWidth = 50;
    int tileHeight = 50;

    //flags
    bool editing = true;
};
```

But when I declare the "Level" object in the "LevelEditor" constructor like so, I get a stack overflow:

```cpp
class LevelEditor
{
public:
    LevelEditor(int w, int h, Shader* shader)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                tile[x][y] = new WorldSprite(tileWidth * x, tileHeight * y, tileWidth, tileHeight, shader);
            }
        }
        //NOTE: width and height both equal 50
        level = Level(width, height);
    }

    //...
private:

    //...
    Level level;

    WorldSprite* tile[300][300];

    //tile characteristics
    int tileWidth = 50;
    int tileHeight = 50;

    //flags
    bool editing = true;
};
```

This makes me wonder what the difference is between declaring a variable in the class definition and in the constructor is besides the fact of the time of defining the variable. Any idea of what the cause could be? and how I could declare the "Level" object in the constructor without having to put anything on the heap?

EDIT:
"Level" class definition in case it is helpful:

```cpp
class Level
{
public:
    Level(int w, int h)
    {
        Worldwidth = w;
        Worldheight = h;

        for (unsigned int y = 0; y < Worldheight; y++)
        {
            for (unsigned int x = 0; x < Worldwidth; x++)
            {
                grid[x][y] = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    Level(){}
    ~Level()
    {
        for (auto it = tiles.begin(); it != tiles.end(); ++it)
        {
            delete *it;
        }
        tiles.clear();

        for (auto it = entities.begin(); it != entities.end(); ++it)
        {
            delete *it;
        }
        entities.clear();
    }

    void draw()
    {

    }
private:

    int Worldwidth;
    int Worldheight;

    int grid[300][300];

    std::vector<Tile*> tiles;
    std::vector<Entity*> entities;
};
```

Comment: Does class Level has correct copy constructor?Show us your Level class definition.

Comment: http://ideone.com/inKGMR  That is at least the number of bytes one of your `LevelEditor` objects takes up.  Reconsider your design.  You are declaring single objects that are over 300K bytes in size.

Comment: @RonTang isn't a copy constructor something c++ automatically give classes without it having to be defined by hand?

Comment: @CharlesHetterich You are getting a stack overflow.  That indicates that your objects are possibly too large to be copied and you're running out of stack space.  Instead of arrays, use a vector and size it appropriately in the constructor.

Comment: @CharlesHetterich Also, your `Level` class will not be safely copied due to your class using pointers (vector of pointers) as members.   It requires a user defined copy constructor and assignment operator, as the defaults will not be adequate.  Your destructor for `Level` is deleting all the allocated instances in the vector, thus `level = Level(...)` leaves `level` with bogus values.  I suggest you use vectors, and probably `std::shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just commented out the 300x300 array and the level defined in the constructor worked. But why does a pointer affect if there is a stack overflow if the pointer is on the heap?

Comment: @CharlesHetterich Look at the code I linked to in my comment.  Do you see  the number of bytes that definition takes up?  It is the `array` that is not on the heap, and it is the array that is taking up all of this space.

Comment: @CharlesHetterich  PaulMcKenzie is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.  I will try to address the `stack overflow` error.  The other issue is that your `Level` class is not safely copyable -- that can be taken care of by utilizing smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`.

First, your classes use 300 x 300 arrays of `T`, in one case, `T` is a `WorldSprite*` the other is `int`.  Arrays this size declared as members will balloon the size of each of your objects that contain them to hundreds of kilobytes in size.  This will at some point take a toll on the stack.

So you should remove these definitions, and instead use `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>

class LevelEditor
{
public:
    LevelEditor(int w, int h, Shader* shader) : 
                tile(w,std::vector<WorldSprite*>(h))
                editing(true), width(w), height(h)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                tile[x][y] = new WorldSprite(tileWidth * x, tileHeight * y, 
                                             tileWidth, tileHeight, shader);
        }
        level = Level(width, height);
    }
private:
    Level level;
    int width, height;
    std::vector<std::vector<WorldSprite*>> tile;
    bool editing;
};
```

Here is the `Level` class with the same type of changes:

```
#include <vector>
//...
class Level
{
public:
    Level(int w, int h) : Worldwidth(w), Worldheight(h), 
                          grid(300, std::vector<int>(300, -1))
    {}

    Level(){}

    ~Level()
    {
        for (auto it = tiles.begin(); it != tiles.end(); ++it)
        {
            delete *it;
        }
        tiles.clear();

        for (auto it = entities.begin(); it != entities.end(); ++it)
        {
            delete *it;
        }
        entities.clear();
    }

    void draw()
    {
    }
private:
    int Worldwidth;
    int Worldheight;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> >grid;
    std::vector<Tile*> tiles;
    std::vector<Entity*> entities;
};
```

Note that the vector replaces the array, and it will use heap memory to initialize.  In the `Level` class, we initialize the vector and set all the entries to `-1` in one single call of the vector's constructor.

The reason why this will not hike the size of your objects to very high amounts is that vector will create its data on the heap (unless you have some sort of custom allocator that gets the memory from another source).  Thus the size of your classes will be reasonable (probably less than 100 bytes).

---

The other issue is that your `Level` class is not safely copyable (neither is the `LevelEditor`, but I will leave it alone, as the same set of changes can be done).

The problem will be this line:

`level = Level(width, height);`

The problem with this line is that the assignment operator will be called and the copy constructor may be called.  If you look at your `Level` class, it has a destructor that removes all the pointers from the vectors that contain pointers.  This will be disastrous if you copy `Level` objects, since you will be destroying all of your data due to temporaries being destroyed.

If there is no sense of which `Level` actually owns the pointers, and it comes down to "whoever is the last man standing is the owner", and you will actually be *sharing* pointers between `Level` instances (that's why it's called *shared_ptr*) then you can use this solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
//...
class Level
{
public:
    Level(int w, int h) : Worldwidth(w), Worldheight(h), 
                          grid(300, std::vector<int>(300, -1))
    {}

    Level(){}
    void draw()
    {
    }
private:
    int Worldwidth;
    int Worldheight;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tile>> tiles;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Entity>> entities;
};
```

Note how there is no destructor code -- there need not be any.  The deletion is all done by the `shared_ptr`, so there is no work for you to do -- everything is managed.   What will happen is that the last `Level` that gets destroyed that you shared the pointers with will do the actual deletion.  So when this line is done

`level = Level(width, height);`

the copying of the `Level` objects bumps up and down the internal `shared_ptr`'s reference count, leaving you with a reference count of 1 (that is the final `level` on the left-hand side of the `=` sign).

See here for usage of `std::shared_ptr`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Please note that you may want to use `std::unique_ptr` if ownership is an issue.  I suggest you search SO for usages of `std::unique_ptr`.  I showed you `std::shared_ptr` since it is the most straightforward at this point (but again, may not suit all your needs - YMMV).